# Disabling anti-aliasing on emacs GUI?

Tags: fonts

Using the GUI version of emacs, I would like to the fonts to match the rest of my system.

I have changed my the font to the same as my terminal font, but the anti-aliasing makes it look much different.

Is there anyway to disable anti-aliasing from emacs for the X server version?

Or do I need to look into `fonts.conf` or something similar?

I am using `Fedora 23` and `emacs-24.5`.

Comment: I use `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font .  "Consolas-19:antialias=true:hinting=false" ))`. You could try with `antialias=false` but that gave me weird looking fonts.

Comment: Search in the preference, there is an option "antialias". Turn it off.